# DeserializationException on consuming message from Kafka topic

Tags: java, exception, apache-kafka, deserialization

I have a problem with my kafka consumer, when consumer start reading from topic, message deserialization fails and block my consumer. Looks like it can't deserialize massage that has been changed. You can reproduce the problem, just produce message change it structure and produce it again on the same consumer. How I can handle this case and avoid a blocking of consumer?

Error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCdRn.png)

```
// initial message 
class Message {
    String name;
}

// Message after change 
class Message {
    List<String> names;
}

// When Exception throws, this code does not execute
@KafkaHandler
public void listenOnMessage(Message message) {
    log.info("message: {}", message);

    // ...
}
```

Update:
basically problem was in producer, it from some point in time started publish different messages structure, solution is simple, all I need to add is ErrorHandling on consumer side, retry logic and recovery. Basically discussion on reddit and repos with similar issue and solution you can find here https://www.reddit.com/r/apachekafka/comments/10dd0qg/how_to_handle_a_poison_pill_on_consumer_side/

Comment: You can configure a deserializer that can handle both. It's a really common issue with no single answer though, it depends on your use case.

Comment: Sorry, no, we cannot reproduce that without the rest of your Spring configuration.  Refer [mcve], and please add logs as text, not images. You may want to double check the Spring Kafka documentation on handling JSON events and "trusted packages".

Comment: After some research I found cause of issue and as summary I can share this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/apachekafka/comments/10dd0qg/how_to_handle_a_poison_pill_on_consumer_side/)

Comment: I would like to encourage you, @ValeriyFokin, to write a full answer on your own question and also accept it so other readers see that you solved the problem. :)